# How to take screenshot of TV.app on MacOS Catalina

Tags: screenshot, macos-catalina

Just to be clear: I am not talking about AppleTV but the TV.app in Mac.OS Catalina.
Usually to take a screenshot you press Shift+Command+3 or +4.
But when you do that within the TV.app you will get a black screen as Apple blocked that option.
Any idea how to go about it?